# Run-time error ' 6' overflow: Microsoft Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to solve this overflow in my excel sheet and still not able to solve it.
I knew that my data is really a lot (more than 32767 rows).
please take a look a my code and help me advise on this.
Thanks.

This is remove Macro

```
Sub Remove()
'
' Remove Macro
'
Dim Ctr As Integer
Dim CtrS As String
Dim EOF As Boolean
Dim LstStr As String
Dim CurStr As String

Ctr = 8
LstStr = ""
Cutstr = ""
EOF = False

Do While Not EOF
    CtrS = CStr(Ctr)
    CurStr = Range("A" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("B" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("C" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("D" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("E" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("F" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("G" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("H" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("I" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("J" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
             Range("K" & CtrS).Value
    If CurStr <> "----------" Then
        If CurStr = LstStr Then
            'Clear content A to N, except L
            Range("A" & CtrS, "L" & CtrS).ClearContents
            Range("N" & CtrS, "O" & CtrS).ClearContents
        Else
            LstStr = CurStr
        End If
    Else
        EOF = True
    End If
    Ctr = Ctr + 1
Loop
'
End Sub
```

When I tried to debug, the error point to here:

```
Ctr = Ctr + 1
```

Comment: In VBA an integer is a signed 16 bit value for compatibility with VB4 16 bit code. Declare `as Long` for a 32 bit signed integer (+/- 2 billion).

Comment: You probably have the data that exceeds integer type limit, change to long as @Tim Williams says.

Comment: @Noodles Thz for your advise

Comment: @TedoG.Thz..Already followed his answer and problem solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all your `Integer` declarations to `Long`

```
Dim Ctr As Long
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

you've been already been given the answer

you may also consider the following refcatoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Remove()
    '
    ' Remove Macro
    '
    Dim Ctr As Long
    Dim EOF As Boolean
    Dim LstStr As String
    Dim CurStr As String

    Ctr = 8
    Do
        CurStr = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A" & Ctr).Resize(, 11).Value)), "-")
        If CurStr <> "----------" Then
            If CurStr = LstStr Then
                'Clear content A to N, except L
                Range("A" & Ctr & ":L" & Ctr & ",N" & Ctr & ":O" & Ctr).ClearContents
            Else
                LstStr = CurStr
            End If
        Else
            EOF = True
        End If
        Ctr = Ctr + 1
    Loop While Not EOF
End Sub
```

where

- `Option Explicit`

  would have spotted that `Cutstr = ""` typo (it should have been `Curstr = ""`)
- no need for

  ```
  Dim CtrS As String
  ```

  and all its subsequent initialization and use

  since `Ctr` variable of `Long` type  will be implicitly cast to a `String` when combined to another `String` variable through the `&` operator
- no need for

  ```
  LstStr = ""
  Cutstr = ""
  ```

  since `String` variables are always initialized to an empty one at their declaration
- no need for

  ```
  EOF = False
  ```

  since `Boolean` variables are always initialized to `False` at their declaration
- `While Not EOF`

  moved to the `Loop` part of the `Do - Loop` block

  since `EOF` first value is always `False`
- change

  ```
  CurStr = Range("A" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
           Range("B" & CtrS).Value & "-" & _
           ...
           Range("K" & CtrS).Value
  ```

  to

  ```
  CurStr = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A" & Ctr).Resize(, 11).Value)), "-")
  ```

  where you take advantage of the [`Resize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx) property of `Range` object and the [`Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264098.aspx) function

  the double `Application.Transpose()` is there to return a one dimensional array since:

  - `Range("A" & Ctr).Resize(, 11).Value`

    would return a **two** dimensional array of 1 row and 11 columns
  - `Application.Transpose(Range("A" & Ctr).Resize(, 11).Value))`

    would return a 2 dimensional array of 11 rows and 1 columns
  - `Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A" & Ctr).Resize(, 11).Value)))`

    would finally return a 1 dimensional array of 11 elements
- `Range("A" & Ctr & ":L" & Ctr & ",N" & Ctr & ":O" & Ctr)`

  takes advantage of one of possible Range() arguments specifications, specifically

  ```
  Range("firstRangeAddress, secondRangeAddress"")
  ```

  where that comma between the two addresses acts as a `Union()` operator